# procedure, setting variable, repeat until, substring from one variable, mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, substring, repeat

I am looking for help with my sql procedure.
I would like to substring in loop each username, and alias from two input arguments and add it into table users. I have two procedures.

Sorry for Polish variable names and procedure names.

My first procedure is

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dodajZawodnika`(IN `dane` VARCHAR(50), IN `wyswietlanie` VARCHAR(50))
        NO SQL

    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT 1 = 1 from zawodnicy where danezawodnika = dane AND dowyswietlenia=wyswietlanie) THEN

            BEGIN 
                Select id from zawodnicy where danezawodnika=dane AND dowyswietlenia=wyswietlanie;
            END;

            ELSE
            BEGIN

            Insert INTO zawodnicy (danezawodnika, dowyswietlenia) VALUES(dane, wyswietlanie);



            SELECT last_insert_id() AS ID;

            END;
        END IF; 
END;
```

My second procedure is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `stworzSklad`(IN `dane` VARCHAR(1500), IN `pseudo` VARCHAR(1000))
    NO SQL
BEGIN 

    DECLARE counter INTEGER;
    DECLARE zawodnik VARCHAR(1500);
    DECLARE pseudonim VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE zawodnicy VARCHAR(1500);
    DECLARE pseudonimy VARCHAR(1000);

    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
      BEGIN
        -- ERROR
      ROLLBACK;
    END;

    DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
     BEGIN
        -- WARNING
     ROLLBACK;
    END;

    set counter = 0;
    set @zawodnicy = dane;
    set @pseudonimy = psuedo;

    select @zawodnicy, @pseudonimy;

    REPEAT
        set zawodnik=(SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@zawodnicy, ',', 1)));
        set pseudonim=(SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@pseudonimy, ',', 1)));

        call dodajZawodnika(zawodnik, pseudonim);

        SELECT RIGHT(@zawodnicy, TRIM(length(@zawodnicy) - length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@zawodnicy, ',', 1)) - 1)) into @zawodnicy;
        SELECT RIGHT(@pseudonimy, TRIM(length(@pseudonimy) - length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@pseudonimy, ',', 1)) - 1)) into @pseudonimy;

        select zawodnik as 'zawodnik', pseudonim as 'pseudonim', dane as 'dane', pseudo as 'pseudo', @zawodnicy as 'zawodnicy', @pseudonimy as 'pseudonimy';

        set counter = counter + 1;

    UNTIL (@zawodnicy = ''  or counter = 30)
    END REPEAT;

    select counter;

END
```

I am fighting with it from about 2 hours.
I would like to use also transaction for this insert.
Please help me with this little problem.
How to make this in proper way?
Now, calling stworzSklad procedure make endless loop (ofc without counter in until condition) and any of user was not inserted in my table.

Cheers!